# facing issue regarding retrofit login in android

Tags: java, android, authentication, retrofit2

I am facing an issue with retrofit login. when i run the application in my cell phone , i logged in with a registered user... login successful... but when i logged out and want to re-login with another account the "application logged me in with the previous account" ... i am not understanding what is this issue please help.
i am not understanding why this issue is occurring with my application.

Note: i am using retrofit (with Firebase) in the application for signup and login.
Thanks

here is the code of my Login Class

```
    private Button forgot ;
    private TextView CreactAccount_text;
    private EditText login_email , login_password;
    private ProgressDialog mLoginProgress;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_);
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.login_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (getSupportActionBar()!= null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
//        Realm.init(this);
        // User Session Manager



        Window window = getWindow();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            window.setStatusBarColor(getColor(R.color.login_statusbar_color));
        }
        else {
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.login_statusbar_color));
        }

        mLoginProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);


        CreactAccount_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ui_crateaccount_text);
        forgot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ui_btn_forgot);
        forgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent forgot_password = new Intent(Login_Activity.this , Forgot_Password_Activity.class);
                startActivity(forgot_password);
            }
        });
        CreactAccount_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent move_signup = new Intent(Login_Activity.this , Signup_Activity.class);
                startActivity(move_signup);
            }
        });

        login_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ui_login_email);
        login_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ui_login_password);
        findViewById(R.id.ui_signin).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                usersignin();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
            finish();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(
                R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.slide_right_out);
        AppUtils.hideSoftKeyboard(this);
    }

    public void usersignin(){


        final String email = login_email.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = login_password.getText().toString().trim();


        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            login_email.setError("Email is not correctly formated");
            login_email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.isEmpty()){
            login_password.setError("password is required");
            login_password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.length() < 6){
            login_password.setError("Password should be atleast 6 characters");
            login_password.requestFocus();
            return;

        }


        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){

            mLoginProgress.setTitle("Logging In");
            mLoginProgress.setMessage("Please wait while we check your credentials.");
            mLoginProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            mLoginProgress.show();

            SharedPreferenceUtil.storeStringValue(Login_Activity.this, Constants.USERNAME,email);
            SharedPreferenceUtil.storeStringValue(Login_Activity.this,Constants.PASSWORD,password);

            RetrofitUtil.createProviderAPI().userLogin(email , password).enqueue(loginUser(this));



        }


    }
    @Override
    public void onLoginUser(RetrofitClientLogin data) {
        if(data.getType().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){

            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

            UtilFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(Constants.EVENT_LOGIN,Constants.KEY_EMAIL,login_email.getText().toString());
            SharedPreferenceUtil.storeBooleanValue(this,Constants.ISUSERLOGGEDIN,true);
            if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getBooleanExtra(Constants.IS_RESULT_ACTIVITY,false)){
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
            }else{
                hideProgressDialog();
                openAcitivty(Home_Activity.class);

            }
            loginOnFirebase();

        }
    }



    private void loginOnFirebase(){
        final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser == null){
            final String email = login_email.getText().toString();
            final String password = login_password.getText().toString();
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(Login_Activity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                                hideProgressDialog();
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        });
                            }else{
                                hideProgressDialog();
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    }


    protected void openAcitivty(Class<?> cls) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, cls);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    protected void showProgressDialog(String msg) {
        try {
            if (mLoginProgress != null && !mLoginProgress.isShowing()) {
                mLoginProgress.setMessage(msg);
                mLoginProgress.show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void hideProgressDialog() {
        try {
            if (mLoginProgress != null && mLoginProgress.isShowing()) {
                mLoginProgress.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignup(RetrofitClientLogin data) {

    }


    @Override
    public void OnError(String error) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        Toast.makeText(this,error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: Please specify your code what u tried

Comment: ok @GowthamanM i am editing my question

Comment: @GowthamanM plese check i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You're using SharedPreferences for storing login credentials. Once user enters valid login credentials (login ID and password) you store it in SharedPreferences in `usersignin()` method.

```
SharedPreferenceUtil.storeStringValue(Login_Activity.this, Constants.USERNAME, email);
SharedPreferenceUtil.storeStringValue(Login_Activity.this, Constants.PASSWORD, password);
```

Now, I am *assuming* (you only posted LoginActivity and didn't mention other parts) that your app has Splash page. Which appears before Login page. In which you decide whether the user has already logged in or not (using SharedPreference values). If yes, redirect to Home page else Login page.

The fix for this issue is very simple. When user logs out from the app, you need to clear SharedPreferences as well.

Like this,

```
SharedPreferenceUtil.storeStringValue(Login_Activity.this, Constants.USERNAME, null);
SharedPreferenceUtil.storeStringValue(Login_Activity.this, Constants.PASSWORD, null);
```

Comment: That's not enough to understand the problem. You need to post the relevant code.